# Prediction interval for function of binary outcomes in GLM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, prediction, prediction-interval

I have a large data set with binary outcomes $\vec{y} = (y_1,\dots,y_n)$ with $y_i\in\{0,1\}$ and covariates $\mathbf{X} = (\vec{x}_1, \dots ,\vec{x}_n)^\top$. One of the goals of the model I am fitting is to forecast the risk weighted sum

$$r = \sum_{i=1}^{n_{\text{future}}} z_i \widetilde{y}_i$$

where the $\widetilde{y}_i\in\{0,1\}$ for $i = 1,\dots, n_{\text{future}}$ are unknown future outcomes and I know the current covariates, $\widetilde{\vec{x}}_i$s, and the $z_i$s. I want to provide 90 pct. prediction interval for $r$

I have fitted at logistic regression so far. A naive approach would be to compute the predicted probabilities, $\widehat{\widetilde{p}}_i$s, simulate $\widetilde{y}_i$s, compute $r$, and find the 5% and 95% quanetile. As shown below this fail to account for the uncertainty in the parameter estimates an provide far from the right coverage (however the example is with a small sample).

I have three questions below highlighted in bold and a simulation example at the end to clarify the setup and backup my claims.

## Good argument that the parameter uncertainty is not important

**What are good arguments that the parameter uncertainty is not important?** I have a large data set (more than 1 million observations and 40k cases with 50-100 parameters) and the standard errors of the estimates are quite small. **Are there any metric I can use to quantity this?**

## Bootstrap / simulation

Another idea would be to use the large sample approximation that

$$\widehat{\vec{\beta}} - \vec{\beta} \sim N(\vec{0}, (\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{W}\mathbf{X})^{-1})$$

where $\mathbf{X}$ is the design matrix and $\mathbf{W}$ are working weights at convergence. Thus, one could draw $\widetilde{\vec{\beta}}$ from $N(\widehat{\vec{\beta}}, (\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{W}\mathbf{X})^{-1})$, compute the predicted probabilities, $\widehat{\widetilde{p}}_i$s, using $\widetilde{\vec{\beta}}$, simulate $\widetilde{y}_i$s, compute $r$, and find the 5% and 95% quanetile. I gather the results will be very close to Bayesian credible interval if I had used an uninformative prior.

The above is nice since I do not have to refit the model. **However, I am not sure what the pit falls might be or if this is an acceptable method.** It does seem to have reasonably close coverage in the example. Further, it is along the lines of the suggestion in chapter 4 of

> Wood, Simon N.. Generalized Additive Models: An Introduction with R (Chapman & Hall/CRC Texts in Statistical Science). CRC Press. Kindle Edition.

which is neat since I also have a GAM fit and want to do a similar thing. I gather an alternative would be a parametric or non-parametric bootstrap. However, I would prefer to avoid this due to the computation time (especially for GAM).

## Example

Here is simulation example which may make it more clear

```
#####
# define function to simulate
sim_coverage <- function(
  formula_fit = y ~ X1 + X2 + X3, spec = 6, n_trials = 1e3){
  #####
  # setup cluster to decrease computation time
  require(parallel)
  cl <- makeCluster(spec)
  on.exit(stopCluster(cl))
  clusterEvalQ(cl, {
    #####
    # parameter for simulation
    n_test  <- 10000
    n_train <- 1000
    n_sim <- 1000

    n <- n_test + n_train
    is_test <- 1:n_test

    invisible()
  })
  clusterSetRNGStream(cl)

  #####
  # simulate
  out <- parSapply(cl, 1:n_trials, function(...){
    # simulate variables
    X <- matrix(runif(3 * n, -1, 1), ncol = 3)
    beta. <- runif(3, -1, 1)
    y <- 1/(1 + exp(-(X %*% beta. - 0.5))) > runif(n) 
    z <- exp(rnorm(n_test))

    test_dat  <- data.frame(y = y[ is_test], X[ is_test, ])
    train_dat <- data.frame(y = y[-is_test], X[-is_test, ])

    # fit model
    fit <- glm(formula_fit, binomial(), train_dat)

    # simulate outcomes for weighted z given model estimates
    y_hat <- predict(fit, test_dat, type = "response")
    sim_1 <- replicate(n_sim, {
      y_sim <- y_hat > runif(n_test)
      sum(y_sim * z)
    })

    # draw beta and then simulate outcome
    beta_hat <- fit$coefficients
    cov_chol <- chol(vcov(fit))
    mm <- model.matrix(terms(fit), test_dat)
    sim_2 <- replicate(
      n_sim, {
        beta_sim <- drop(beta_hat + t(cov_chol) %*% rnorm(length(beta_hat))) 
        y_sim <- 1/(1 + exp(-(mm %*% beta_sim))) > runif(n_test)
        sum(y_sim * z)
      })

    # compute if covered. It should be 5-95%
    q1 <- quantile(sim_1, c(.05, .95))
    q2 <- quantile(sim_2, c(.05, .95))

    actual <- sum(test_dat$y * z)
    c(
      `conditional on estimates` = q1[1] <= actual && q1[2] >= actual, 
      `simulated parameters`     = q2[1] <= actual && q2[2] >= actual)
  })

  # return coverage
  rowSums(out) / ncol(out)
}

# use function with correctly specified model
library(parallel)
set.seed(seed <- 39160006)
sim_coverage(formula_fit = y ~ X1 + X2 + X3)
#R> conditional on estimates     simulated parameters 
#R>                    0.552                    0.910 

# use function with misspecified model
set.seed(seed)
sim_coverage(formula_fit = y ~ X1)
#R> conditional on estimates     simulated parameters 
#R>                0.558                    0.885
```

---

My questions are vaguely related to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/42958/81865). However, the OP's questions is about a single response from an exponential family and not a variable which is a function of many observations from an exponential family (the function being non-linear w.r.t. the linear predictors).

Comment: I sympathize a lot with the Bayesian approach, especially unless the number of samples at each factor level combination is large.  If you've got a large dataset, you can check whether on separate test data (i.e. not used in the model development) those predicted to have 0 to 5%, >5 to 10% etc. probability really do (or at least within the prediction interval).

Comment: Thanks @Björn. Your answer is that you think that my second approach is valid. I dont get how your latter part answer my questions. It seems like you talk about multiple (binary) responses whereas I talk about a confidence intervals for a single variable which is a function of binary variables. I get that I can use e.g., cross validation to check that the method work. This is not what I am asking for though.

Comment: You were asking about evaluation metrics. that would be an obvious one for prediction.

Comment: True -- good point! I was looking more for something I could compute directly from the fit e.g., by looking $\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{W}\mathbf{X}$.

Comment: Which is upper limit of the risk weighted summation? If I read your code correctly, it’s $n_{test}=1000$ in your example, and it’s a fixed number, not a random variable.

Comment: @DeltaIV The upper bound for $r$ is the sum of the $z_i$s. There are `n_test  <- 10000` unknown binary responses in the simulation. The number of unknown binary variables and corresponding known covariates $\widetilde{\vec{x}}_i$s and weights $z_i$s is fixed and not random.

Comment: @BenjaminChristoffersen thanks. What about the weights $z_i$, instead? From your code it seems to me they are log-normal random variables, iid. Is that correct? Do you need the prediction interval to incorporate the uncertainty in the weights?

Comment: @DeltaIV No those a known in advance. I simulate in the code only to get weights that are different.

Comment: Excellent! Then I think it's fairly easy to answer your question. I'm a bit busy these days, so I'll write a draft answer now. Let me know if I got the gist of the issue right: if so, then I'll refine it in the next days.

Comment: by the way, when you generate the future outcomes $\widetilde{y}_i\in\{0,1\}$ for $i = 1,\dots, n_{\text{future}}$, the $\widetilde{\vec{x}}_i$ are fixed, right? They don't vary between an experiment and the other. If they do, the question is ill-posed - we need to know the distribution of the $\widetilde{\vec{x}}_i$ to have a chance of answering.

Comment: Yes, the $\widetilde{\vec{x}}_i$s are fixed when I generate the $\widetilde{y}_i$s. The $\widetilde{\vec{x}}_i$s are known and we assume the probabilities that the $\widetilde{y}_i$s equals 1 depend deterministically on the $\widetilde{\vec{x}}_i$s.